# HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog showing an error- Symbol 'term <none>.yetus.audience' is missing from the classpath. how to resolve this?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hbase

My input is `HBase` table. first I am loading the data and function `withCatalog` will return `Dataframe`.

```
def withCatalog(cat: String): DataFrame = {
  sqlContext
    .read
    .options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> cat))
    .format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark")
    .load()
}
val allrulesDF = withCatalog("personDb:employeeTable")
allrulesDF.show()
```

`HBaseTableCatalog` line showing below error

- Symbol `term <none>.yetus.audience` is missing from the `classpath.` This symbol is required by `<none>`. Make sure that term audience is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`. A full rebuild may help if `HBaseTableCatalog.class` was compiled against an incompatible version of `<none>.yetus`.
- Symbol `term org.apache.yetus` is missing from the classpath. This symbol is required by `<none>`. Make sure that term yetus is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`. A full rebuild may help if `HBaseTableCatalog.class` was compiled against an incompatible version of `org.apache`.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to spark cannot load hbase jar.

If you use hbase2.1+, you can find jar likes audience-annotations-*.jar and so on in path `$HBASE_HOME/lib/client-facing-thirdparty`.

And move these jars to spark jars path.